# Is there a way to equalise two different datasets in R?

Tags: r

I have the first dataset called exprs:

```
> class(exprs)
[1] "matrix"
> dim(exprs)
[1] 191812     89
```

My second dataset is called pData:

```
> class(pData)
[1] "data.frame"
> dim(pData)
[1] 89  3
```

However when I run:

```
all(rownames(pData)==colnames(exprs))
[1] FALSE
```

It results in FALSE. I need the final output to be TRUE.

Is this because one class = data.frame while the other class=matrix?

Comment: Have you looked at `cbind(rownames(pData), colnames(exprs))`?

Comment: I think you just print rownames(pData) and colnames(exprs) to the console you will figure out where the difference is. You may also get the index of the first difference by using which(rownames(pData) != colnames(exprs))